# dotnet core shared nuget dependency missing method exception

Tags: .net-core, nuget, dependency-management, missingmethodexception, flurl

I have an internal nuget package that depends on Flurl.Http v1.2, which in turn depends on Flurl >= v2.4. An application depends on this internal package, but also depends on Flurl v2.6.

```
     Application
       /     \
Flurl v2.6   Internal package
               \
             Flurl.Http v1.2
                 \
              Flurl >= v2.4
```

When the application calls a method on the internal package that uses Flurl.Http, it produces an exception: `MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Flurl.Url Flurl.StringExtensions.AppendPathSegment(System.String, System.Object)'.`

It works when I downgrade the application's Flurl dependency to v2.4, but this doesn't feel like a good solution as the application should be able to refernce a higher version. I thought that the solution was to add assembly binding redirects to the `App.config`, but this had no effect. In fact I've read conflicting opinions on whether binding redirects should be used at all in dotnet core.

What am I missing?